# Selecting li's with a particular class name

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
  <li>some data..</li>
  <li>some data..</li>
  <li class="xyz">some data..</li>
  <li class="xyz">some data..</li> 
</ul>
```

How can i select all li's which has "xyz" class ?

Comment: may be this will help [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this selector:

```
var $lis = $('li.xyz');
```

I suggest you follow a basic jQuery tutorial. This one covers just about everything you need to get started: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('ul li.xyz');` to select all `li` elements with a class `xyz`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vCXuK/)**